# Attempted import error: 'persistor' is not exported from './redux/store'

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I'm working on an react app that need to store cart data when page refresh. I decided to use redux-persist. I have implemented base by going through documentation of redux-persist. But when i run my app. it is giving me an error of persistor is exported.
I feel like weirg.

Here is my code of store

```
     import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['cart']
}

const middleware = [thunk];

const persistedReducer  = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)) )
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { persistor, store }
}
```

rootreducer file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import auth from './auth'
import cart from './cart'
import services from './services'
import profile from './profile'
import home from './home';
import alerts from './alert';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    auth,
    cart,
    services,
    profile,
    home,
    alerts
})
  
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    return appReducer(state, action)
}

export default rootReducer;
```

index file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { MuiThemeProvider  } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import theme from './_theme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { getLocation, loadCities } from './redux/actions/auth';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import { persistor,  store} from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} >
       <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
           <App />
        </PersistGate>
       </Provider>     
     </MuiThemeProvider>   
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Not able to understand the root cause. Stuck on this more than 3 hrs
Any help would greatly thankfull

Comment: From redux/store.js you aren't exporting two named variables but a default function. You might want to try with ```import createPersistor from "./redux/store"; const { persistor, store } = createPersistor();```

Answer (score 0):

Export the two separate store and persistor constants in your store.js and delete the default export.
i.e.

```
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```